# setBarTintColor is incorrect

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

here is my code
[image: my code]

I set the UinavigationBar Color with R:54 G:146 B:204,but went I run it,the color is incorrect
[image: result Color]

Can anybody know why?Thank u so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is not specific to setBarTintColor, it is the way iOS applies tint color to elements (slightly modifying it).

If you increase contrast in iOS accessibility settings - you will see another color.

Answer (score 0):

The translucency that `UINavigationBar`s got in iOS 7 messes with the rendering of it's tint color. If you want the color you set exactly you have to turn off the translucency by setting it on your root navigation controller (the property isn't available to the appearance proxy) like this: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO`. See if that fixes your color issue.